# mysql count unique cell combinations, with null

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to use either a PHP file or SQL that will go through a large `data` table to count the amount of combinations of cells and count them in a new `data_sum` table.

I have an idea for a PHP file in the works:

```
$popdata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data");
    while($add = @mysql_fetch_array($popdata)){         
        $qitem1 = "SELECT * FROM data_sum WHERE item1='".$add['item1']."'";
        $ritem1 = mysql_query($qitem1);
        if(mysql_num_rows($ritem1) > 0){
            while($add2 = @mysql_fetch_array($ritem1)){
                $qitem2 = "SELECT * FROM data_sum WHERE item2='".$add['item2']."'";
                $ritem2 = mysql_query($qitem2);
                if (mysql_num_rows($ritem2) > 0){
                    $sql = "UPDATE Count=Count + 1 WHERE item1='".$add['item1']."' AND item2='".$add['item2']."'";
                    $update = mysql_query($sql);
                } else{
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO data_sum (item1, item2) VALUES('$item1', '$item2')";
                    $insert = mysql_query($sql);
            }
        } else{
            $sql = "INSERT INTO data_sum (item1, item2) VALUES('$item1', '$item2')";
            $insert = mysql_query($sql);
        }
```

If I have a table :

```
   `data`
item1  item2
  1           (this row counts to both the '1,2' duo as well as the '1,3')
  1     2
  1     3
  1     3
  2     3
```

And I want to condense it to something like:

```
     `data_sum`
item1  item2  Count
  1      2      2
  1      3      3
  2      3      1
```

Yes, I know there are only 5 rows in `data` and the count is a total of 6. I want the cells with nothing in them to count towards each possible branch. Is there a way to do this in SQL with COUNT or UNIQUE or DISTINCT? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

,
The following query does what you want, by doing the calculation for the two groups separately:

```
select base.item1, base.item2, base.cnt + coalesce(sum(extra.cnt), 0)
from (select item1, item2, count(*) as cnt
      from data
      where item1 is not null and item2 is not null
      group by item1, item2
     ) base join
     (select item1, item2, count(*) as cnt
      from data
      where item1 is null or item2 is null
      group by item1, item2
     ) extra
     on base.item1 = extra.item1 or
        base.item2 = extra.item2 or
        (extra.item1 is null and extra.item2 is null)
group by base.item1, base.item2, base.cnt;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/938e52/5) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Works as intended! Thanks so much!

Comment: I do have a question though. On the SQL fiddle, where does the code on the left go? Is that how I structure my table? Or do I run both queries with PHP? Also, what would I replace 'base' with? Thanks.

Comment: @Kragalon .  . The code on the left is to create tables and such.  The code on the right is to run queries.

Comment: What if I don't need to create a table, and just add on to it?

Comment: Like, thinking that the original data table kept getting data, and needed to be condensed again and update the other table.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, I'm just inexperienced at SQL. Another problem I see is that this doesn't apply to having 3 items correctly, even when adding 'item3' after each 'item2' occurrence. I know it has to do with the AND and OR lines. I don't expect you to rewrite it, as I end up needing like 7 'item' columns, but if you could point me in the right direction, I would be even more grateful. Again, sorry, and thank you!

Comment: @Kragalon . . . If you have a question about more than two items, then ask that as a question.  A comment is an inappropriate place for a question.